# xpath for extracting text from self and child node

Tags: html, xpath, domxpath

here is my situation

i want to select "**Buy 2 Hills Feline Maint Light 10kg and Save a further £4.00!**" only from bellow html

Note: i am using XPath 1.0

```
<div>
    <a>
        <b>
            <u>Multi-Buy:</u>
        </b>
        <br/>
        Buy 
        <b>2</b>
         Hills Feline Maint Light 10kg and 
        <b>
            <font color="#CC0000">Save a further £4.00!</font>
        </b>
        <br/>
        <i>Simply add 2 to your basket.</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

here is my effort

```
//div/a/text()
```

by using this i am missing child node text

```
/div/a//text()
```

if i use this i am getting extra text

Comment: What are the criteria for excluding "Multi-Buy"? To formulate an XPath expression with a predicate we somehow need to understand which nodes you want to exclude. Is that just the first non-blank text descendant that you don't want to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this HTML is not structured in any way that would facilitate extracting this in any clean way, I would propose the following:

```
/div/a//text()[not(. = 'Multi-Buy:' or contains(., 'to your basket'))]
```